# Vaadin custom css - customizing themes

Tags: css, spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle, vaadin

I'm having an issue with using custom theme. I'm using Spring Boot + Vaadin 8 and IntelliJ Idea + Gradle.
I've created a file: `src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css`

```
@import "../valo/styles.css";
.my-split { background: #a983ff; }
```

I've added `@Theme("mytheme")` to my UI class.

I've set the style name on my component: `gridsSplitPane.addStyleName("my-split");`

And now when I run my app it seems that the `mytheme` gets loaded because the background is changed correctly but everything else has no CSS styling - as if the import didn't work: `@import "../valo/styles.css"`

What am I missing here?

I've seen some information that a theme needs to be compiled somehow. Can anyone help me to compile it with Gradle + IntelliJ Idea? Is it also required for plain css customizations like mine?

When I use `@Theme("valo")` instead - everything is loaded correctly, so I'm guessing that all the Valo theme files are loaded correctly from: `vaadin-themes-8.1.0.jar!/VAADIN/themes/valo/...`

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext { springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE' }
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies { classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories { mavenCentral() }

ext { vaadinVersion = '8.1.0' }

dependencies {
    compile('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter')

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports { mavenBom "com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:${vaadinVersion}" }
}
```

**AppMain.java**

```
package example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AppMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

**MyUI.java**

```
package example;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@Theme("mytheme")
@SpringUI(path = "/ui")
public class MyUI extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        Label label = new Label("Customizing theme.");
        label.setStyleName("my-label");

        VerticalLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
        root.addComponent(label);
        root.setSizeFull();
        setContent(root);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you recompiled the themes? In IntelliJ, open the Maven Projects panel, open 'Vaadin' and run 'vaadin:compile-theme'. Then run your project again.

Comment: I'm using Gradle instead of Maven and cannot find any useful information how to proceed with that using Gradle...

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the Gradle part. There must be a solution. Could you maybe share your build.gradle setup?

Comment: I've updated the post with some example files that can be used to reproduce.

Comment: I've been looking around a bit, but couldn't really find a clear solution on how to compile the theme using Gradle. However, there is a command line solution that you could try. Official Vaadin doc: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-compiling.html

Comment: I've tried creating SCSS and compiling it but no luck. Although the `styles.css` file was generated successfully, the whole page still displays as if there was no styling for it. I used command:  `java -cp vaadin-sass-compiler-0.9.13.jar;vaadin-themes-8.1.0.jar;. com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.scss src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css` and utilized example from vaadin documentation for `styles.scss`, containing just: `@import "../valo/styles.scss";
@mixin mytheme { @include valo; }`

Comment: As far as I know (I have a gradle project running with custom theme) you do not need to compile themes. This is done by Vaadin at runtime if you use scss files.

Comment: What you're saying is in line with the documentation however If I don't compile SCSS and want to rely on on-the-fly generation by simply putting `styles.scss` in proper location (as mentioned earlier in post & comment), then it is not working too and I'm getting standard error output:

`Sep 13, 2017 9:08:22 AM org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils guestRawServletPath
WARNING: More than one Servlet Mapping defined. WebSocket may not work org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationServletRegistration`. Could you please try to compile and run my example files and see what happens? Are you using Spring too?

Comment: Although the documentation says about "Plain old CSS themes", I wonder how this could work because the compiled Valo CSS styles are all prefixed with ".valo" selector which I think will never be set as style class to the main div element when switching to other themes like "mytheme".

Comment: The log you posted is just a warning. Maybe try the default context path (not "/ui") and removing other dependencies than Vaadin, just to narrow the error.

Comment: Can you post the compiled SCSS result CSS?

Comment: I got it working with your example with some modification, I will post it as answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. 

The mentioned warning appears when I add `com.vaadin:vaadin-push` dependency. I still have no clue how to fix it...

Comment: You are welcome. Please open a new question for that issue if you need help. I did not work with Vaadin push so far.

Comment: I've done that. If anybody can help here I'd appreciate it since I'm still pretty much evaluating Vaadin and Spring in tandem and just going through tutorials, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113772/vaadin-spring-boot-errors-cannot-enhance-configuration-and-more-than-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close to get it working. To use a custom SCSS theme, put the following in the `styles.scss`:

```
@import "../valo/valo";

.mytheme {
    @include valo;
}
```

The basic difference with the content you mentioned in the comments is the way to include Valo in your theme.

**EDIT**

Your original question was about CSS theme. As far as I can see, CSS themes shouldn't work with including Valo because most styles are prefixed with `.valo` CSS selector and switching to your custom theme will add the CSS class `mytheme` instead of default `valo` to the main div element. I even tested to add the `valo` CSS class in the final HTML (Firefox inspector) which then shows styles as expected. Feels like a Vaadin bug. So, I recommend using SCSS themes which also have more features than CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Here a quick tutorial

**"How to use a custom theme with Vaadin 8 and SPRING boot application"**

1. Create a Vaadin Application with Spring BOOT, sbt, SCALA and Vaadin8
2. Create a new Vaadin application using maven archetype

Maven -> [x] Create from archetype -> com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-application -> vaadin-archetype-application:8.0.0

[image: crate vaadin app from archetype]

3. Copy vaadin custom theme from maven archetype app to your SPRING Vaadin 8 app:

Copy entire **VAADIN** directory
(src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme)

to

src/main/resources/VAADIN/themes/mytheme

[image: copy vaadin directory]

4. Change

`@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {
}`

5. [OPTIONAL] Change the name of the theme to your liking

Rename:

```
VAADIN/themes/mytheme/mytheme.scss -> othertheme.scss
VAADIN/themes/mytheme/mytheme.scss -> change mixin name @mixin othertheme { ... }
VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.scss -> change @import "othertheme.scss" | .othertheme{} | @include othertheme;
```

More info in these screencasts:

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwhg3NrOLVA) Introduction to Vaadin - Your first application with Framework 8

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USF35wZPxZk) Community Answer: Creating new Vaadin Themes in Spring Applications